# what is the correct way to set a Date() object based on user input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm making an age verification modal and I'm a little stuck.

On lines 4-7 I create a javascript date object and try to fill it with the month, date and year, but it has become apparent to me that each of the lines 5-7 is overwritting the previous one.

```
$('#tier3').change(function(){
    var tier1 = $('#tier1').find(":selected").text();
     var tier2 = $('#tier2').find(":selected").text();
     var tier3 = $('#tier3').find(":selected").text();
     var userDOB = new Date();
     userDOB.setMonth(tier1);
     userDOB.setDate(tier2);
     userDOB.setFullYear(tier3);
     var now = Date.now();
     userAge = now - userDOB;
     if( userAge >= 588591547188){
        set_popup_cookie();
        popup_wrapper.style.visibility="hidden";
     }else {
        /*  window.location = "http://www.smokefree.gov/"; */
     }
});
```

I also tried substituting lines 4-7 with

```
var userDOB = Date.parse(tier . " " . tier2 . ", " . tier3 );
```

But I got a syntax error

Comment: The concatenation character in JavaScript is `+`.

Comment: When I run a JSFiddle with hard-coded values, it works successfully.  Maybe something to do with your JQuery output? http://jsfiddle.net/f6aZ8/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Date` constructor `new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);`

as below

```
var userDOB = new Date(tier3, tier2, tier1);
var now = Date.now();
userAge = now - userDOB;
 if( userAge >= 588591547188){
    set_popup_cookie();
    popup_wrapper.style.visibility="hidden";
 }else {
    /*  window.location = "http://www.smokefree.gov/"; */
 }
```

check `tier3, tier2, tier1` having expected values before calculating age

Comment: @JackPilowsky what are the values you get for `tier3, tier2, tier1`?

Comment: Oh, month has to be 1-12?

Comment: @JackPilowsky yes, it should be valid month